# Constantly check when a CSS class is added

Tags: javascript, jquery, video.js

I'm trying to display an element when a video is paused.
I'm using video.js, and currently, classes are added if the video is played, paused, finished etc.

What I can't do is to check using .hasClass() and display the element.
So far I'm using this:

```
 if ($('.video-js').hasClass('vjs-paused')) {
    $('.btn').addClass('show');}
    else {
      $('.btn').removeClass('show');

    }
```

I guess I need to check any changes constantly but i don't really know how to do it.

I've also seen a plugin called watch but not sure how to use it.

This is a codepen:

https://codepen.io/florinsimion/pen/wWjxzA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `.video-js` is not the correct element to listen for.

You can use the videojs API:

```
player.on('pause', function () {
    $('.btn').addClass('show');
});

player.on('play', function () {
    $('.btn').removeClass('show');
});
```

See [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/kXJjpm)

Or listen to events of the video object using jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  $('video#content_video_html5_api').on('play pause', function() {
    $('.btn').toggleClass('show', $(this).get(0).paused);
  });
});
```

Comment: The pen in the answer does work here on Firefox and Chrome (but only not during the advertisement, which I think is normal)

Comment: Works in Firefox for me but not in Chrome.

Comment: The problem with Chrome is, I have AdBlock Plus installed. @FlorinSimion That rings a bell?

Comment: yes ...just wanted to update my comment...Adblocker prevent it.Any ideas on how to stop it from doing that...basically I just want to add a suggestion for the user on pause and at the end of the video (don't want to it to be a add)

Comment: I've added a second solution to my answer, please see how that goes.

Comment: Bear in mind that the jquery solution won't work where video.js is using something other than an HTML5 video element for the playback tech (e.g. Flash, a YouTube player). Sticking to video.js's API will work agnostically of the tech.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to do constantly, which reduces the browser's performance. The `video` element has events that can be listened to:

```
$('.video-js').on('pause play', function () {
  if ($(this).hasClass('vjs-paused')) {
    $('.wrapper').addClass('show');
  } else {
    $('.wrapper').removeClass('show');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for answer...i have updated my pen but still not working.